# How should I send the response in Servlet to Front end?

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I have written a Servlet something like this

```
public class ServletUtil extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1571172240732862415L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String acInfo = request.getQueryString();
    someDao dao = new someDao();
     ArrayList<String> resultAutoComplete=dao.someResults(acInfo);
    out.close();
}
```

}

I have an auto complete Object/wizard in front end and as the user types in it is making Ajax call to back end to grab the list of results. So I have written a Servlet and I am pulling the user input and getting my results from DAO layer.

My question here is how should I send this list(resultAutoComplete) to Front end in the Servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect you to serialise this in some fashion such that the client understands it. e.g. perhaps using [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or similar.

I note that your response content type is `text/html`. So why not simply write each element of your list to your `Writer` *out*, separated by (say) a `<li>` element (with the appropriate unordered/order list entities surrounding this)

Comment: What do you mean by 'write each element of your list to your Writer out, separated by (say) a <li>'? can you show me a sample code

Comment: @Brain for(String acResult:searchAutoCompleteResults) {
         out.write("<li>");
         out.write(acResult);
         out.write("</li>");
        } Some thing like that

Comment: Why do i write each element out. Why can't i send the list as it is.

Comment: Unfortunately the List object doesn't have a suitable method to output the contents of a list in one go. If you were using Scala (say) you could write list.map{"<li>"._}.mkString("\n") or similar

Answer (score 0):

By serializing it to a String and writing it to `out`...

Seriously though, I wouldn't code at the low level Servlet spec. For this kind of return-this-pojo call I would use [Spring 3's RESTful service libraries](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html), or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for (String str : resultAutoComplete)
                {
            out.println(str);
        }
```

Comment: Why can't i use OUT.WRITE(str)?

Comment: Why do i need to iterate through the list. Why can't i send the list at one shot. like OUT.PRINTLN(resultAutoComplete);

Comment: iterating is not required u can directly write the arraylist but tht will not display it properly formatting will b bad, u need 2 iterate if u want to format the display and add some html tags

Answer (score 0):

No json! instead of going through a list in javascript, return a completed `<li>` lists and replace `innerHTML` of `<ul>`.The reason to do so is to give a better performance. Unless you want to do something more flexible, leave things to the back-end.

When do json, you gotta parse string into json object and then loop through and generate html, that's just an extra step. Keep things simple, plus, parsing string could be costly.

If you don't loop through the list and instead do `out.println` the list object, you would likely see the address. also, you need to generate html, so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String option: options){
sb.append("<li>").append(option).append("</li>");
}
out.println(sb);
```

Comment: @lingerdave Why do i need to generate Html? also all i need is a comma separated list, where the front end will  access based on the comma. ie they use comma as a delimiter

Comment: because you want to generate a list of li elements.


it's a choice of whether you wanna have the backend to do the rendering or offload the heavy lifting to the client.

either way works.